# Solr: undefined field text

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

When running latest (05/2012) Solr based n Nutch, folowing the official tutorial by Apache, I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /solr/select. Reason:

    undefined field text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I used the wrong search syntax. You have to use

```
*:*
```

or

```
xmlfield:searchtext
```

It's also a good idea to get familiar with the schema.xml document.